# How much of a QR code needs to be covered to be unreadable?

Tags: structural-engineering, production-technology

How much of a QR code has to be physically covered up to not be readable by a scanner? I'm aware that QR code has max. 30% error correction, so 30% minimum coverage should do it? It also has 3 direction points in the corners, will obstructing one/two of them also prevent reading?

Comment: How is this structural engineering?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the scanner. The position control points contain no data, a scanner could conceivably be designed to read a QR code with none of them visible, some scanners may require the entirety of all 3 points to be visible.  Work is being done on 'QR Code Restoration',  one could conceivably restore a QR code that had >30% damage to the data-containing portions,  even assuming some pixels are entirely obscured,  you could use trial and error to restore some of the missing pixels until the code decodes to some recognisable resource identifier.

At the other extreme, you could also 'obstruct' a QR code enough to confuse some readers, by putting noise in the 'quiet-zone',  which could make a QR code unreadable without obstructing any of the data.